# How can I set attribute to request object in FastAPI from middleware?

Tags: python, middleware, fastapi

How can I set an arbitrary attribute to the `Request` object from the middleware function?

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request

app = FastAPI()


@app.middleware("http")
async def set_custom_attr(request: Request, call_next):
    request.custom_attr = "This is my custom attribute"
    response = await call_next(request)
    return response


@app.get("/")
async def root(request: Request):
    return {"custom_attr": request.custom_attr}
```

This setup is raising an exception,

> AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'custom_attr'

So, **how can I get the *`"This is my custom attribute"`* value in my router?**

Answer (score 25):

We can't attach/set an attribute to the `request` object (correct me if I am wrong).

But, we can make use of the [**`Request.state`**--(Doc)](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/#about-requeststate) property

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request

app = FastAPI()


@app.middleware("http")
async def set_custom_attr(request: Request, call_next):

    request.state.custom_attr = "This is my custom attribute" # setting the value to `request.state`

    response = await call_next(request)
    return response


@app.get("/")
async def root(request: Request):
    return {"custom_attr": request.state.custom_attr} # accessing the value from `request.state`
```

Comment: Well, you're attaching it to the request object. :P

Comment: To be more precise, this is a feature of starlette: https://www.starlette.io/requests/#other-state

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It worked perfectly after hours of head banging. 

Perhaps worth quoting the FastAPI docs: "request.state is a property of each Request object. It is there to store arbitrary objects attached to the request itself, like the database session in this case."

Comment: Link to the aforementioned FastAPI documentation: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/#about-requeststate

Comment: @jlhasson, I hope the answer has the ***same*** reference already.