# How to retrieve user's username after authenticating in Gradio

Tags: python, authentication, gradio

I have a gradio app with a custom login function. I was successful in doing authentication, but then I would like to retrieve and keep the user's username during the session. What would be the solution?

```py
import gradio as gr

def login(email, password):
    """Custom authentication."""

    # Do stuff here
    return True, email

# Application layout
with gr.Blocks(title="My App") as app:
    with gr.Row():
        text = gr.Textbox(label="Text", placeholder="Hello world")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.launch(server_name="0.0.0.0", auth=login)
```

Comment: Found the solution here: https://github.com/gradio-app/gradio/pull/3296

Comment: Maybe you need this one [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64602770/how-can-i-set-attribute-to-request-object-in-fastapi-from-middleware)